# Messagebox while using LostFocus event on editable comboBox

Tags: c#, combobox, messagebox

I face a problem while using LostFocus event for editable comboBox.

```
private void comboBox8_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ...
            else if (8int <= 7int && 8int >= 100)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error description", "Error!", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
            }
            else
            ...
    }
```

Everything works just fine except that messagebox show even if I click with mouse on comboBox text field for edit. There is no messagebox if I use "tab" from a previous field. But direct mouse click cause false messagebox. I need it only be shown when I use "tab" to leave that comboBox or click mouse somewhere else (lostfocus). Can anyone help me with an advice please? I can't find similar situation. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to listen for the `TextBox` part of the `ComboBox` `LostFocus` instead.

```
        private void comboBox8_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox tb = (TextBox)(sender as ComboBox).Template.FindName("PART_EditableTextBox", (sender as ComboBox));
            if (tb != null)
                tb.LostFocus += new RoutedEventHandler(tb_LostFocus);
        }

        void tb_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ...
            else if (8int <= 7int && 8int >= 100)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error description", "Error!", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
            }
            else
            ...
        }
```

Comment: Now there is no false messagebox when you click directly on the drop down arrow, but there is a false messagebox when you click directly on the text still. As I wrote the combobox is editable.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, that works for me:

```
private void comboBox8_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
        ...
        else if (8int <= 7int && 8int >= 100)
        {
            if (!comboBox8.IsKeyboardFocusWithin)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error description", "Error!", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
                }
        }
        else
        ...
        }
```

Thank you!!!

Comment: Did you add this to my answer or is this a different response?

Comment: It's different, but I really appreciate your solution too! Thank you.

Comment: did you add this to your lost focus event? Because when I tried this I get two messages boxes when I leave focus.

Comment: woops ignore my last comment as I still had my other code in there.

Answer (score 0):

There might be another way, not that the one above isn't useful :) Check the source and the originalsource from the RoutedEventArgs.

If the event occurs from within the control, its a internal lostfocus event (combobox have multiple internal controls) and source and the originalsource will have the same type.

This code, works fine for me. When the combobox actually losses focus, i "do something".

```
**private void TimePicker_LostFocus(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.OriginalSource.GetType().Name != e.Source.GetType().Name)
    { 
        Validate();
    }
}**
```

Hope it's helpful

/T